# Issue in setting Images with dynamic columns in grid view

Tags: android, gridview

I want to set images in grid view with multiple columns. Images can be vary in columns.How can i achieve it. Thanks in advance

[Images in GridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENU4g.png)

Comment: I have a grid view. Each row of grid view can have multiple images. e.g first row have 2 images, other can have 3 or 4 images. How i can achieve this kind of functionality. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: you want images or text in gridview

Comment: I want images in gridview.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: Pramod, have you seen the screenshot that i have attached. The grid view can have multiple images in a row. It contains 3 columns in row. But i need variable columns in a row. Check my screenshot that i have attached.

Answer (score 0):

create activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"

    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:numColumns="3" >

    </GridView>

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text=" Computer Languages..." />

</RelativeLayout>][1]][1]
```

Create MainActivity.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        GridView gv;
        Context context;
        ArrayList prgmName;
        public static String [] prgmNameList={"Let Us C","c++","JAVA","Jsp","Microsoft .Net","Android","PHP","Jquery","JavaScript"};
        public static int [] prgmImages={R.drawable.images,R.drawable.images1,R.drawable.images2,R.drawable.images3,R.drawable.images4,R.drawable.images5,R.drawable.images6,R.drawable.images7,R.drawable.images8};
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            gv=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
            gv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, prgmNameList,prgmImages));
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Create a folder by name drawable in res directory. Insert the images into drawable folder by name as below.

```
  public static int [] prgmImages={R.drawable.images,R.drawable.images1,R.drawable.images2,R.drawable.images3,R.drawable.images4,R.drawable.images5,R.drawable.images6,R.drawable.images7,R.drawable.images8};
```

Create the layout as programlist.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="88dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Create Customclass ie CustomAdapter.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    String [] result;
    Context context;
    int [] imageId;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] prgmNameList, int[] prgmImages) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        result=prgmNameList;
        context=mainActivity;
        imageId=prgmImages;
        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return result.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        TextView tv;
        ImageView img;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Holder holder=new Holder();
        View rowView;

        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.program_list, null);
        holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
        holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

        rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+result[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

You will get the Output like..

[image]

Comment: Pramod, have you seen the screenshot that i have attached. The grid view can have multiple images in a row.

Comment: But it will contains 3 columns. But i need variable column number.

Comment: you can set no of column as much as you want

Comment: But that number of columns will be fixed for each row. But i need different column number for each row. e.g for 1st row, 2 columns, for 2nd row, 3 columns etc.

Comment: did you see the screenshot brother??